# Algorithm to find shortest path between two nodes - Does this work?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

**UPDATE: My algorithm is wrong. See this graph: https://pastebin.com/zfuVCRut In processing the elements this way some nodes are marked visited, while they actual reduce distance. Here, node 2 is marked with a large distance, but it actually leads to the shortest path.**

Suppose I wish to know the minimum distance between two nodes `a` and `b` in a unweighted graph. I know we can BFS to do this, but I wanted to do it in reverse.

Assume that the graph is undirected, connected, and unweighted.

So, we want to compute `f(a, b)`. To do this, we have to traverse some edge from `a` that brings us closer to `b`.

We traverse the neighbours of `a`, and compute the minimum of `f(a', b)`.

Now, computing this way will lead to cycles (`f(a, b)` calls `f(a', b)` which will again call `f(a, b)`), but, if we call some function again, that is clearly sub-optimal for the parent function. Our goal is to minimize `f(a, b)`, and if we return to `f(a, b)` after some steps, that is clearly sub-optimal as it adds unnecessary edges.

To counter this we initialize the value to some very large value. Note that this may mean that `f(a', b)` may be higher than expected, but we don't care, we wish to minimize `f(a, b)`.

Pseudcode:

```
int dis[N][N] // N is the number of nodes, initially all -1

function f(a, b) {
   if (a == b) {
      return 0;
   }
   
   if (a and b are neighbours) {
      return 1;
   }

   if (dis[a][b] != -1) {
      return dis[a][b];
   }
   dis[a][b] = infinity;

   min_dis = infinity;

   for (a' in neighbours of a) {
      min_dis = min(min_dis, f(a', b) + 1);
   }

   dis[a][b] = min_dis;
   return ans;
}
```

Does this algorithm work?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions like this are best suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14784753

Comment: @Water this question  would be off-topic at CR, which requires code to be working.